# How to use python to get result from remote terminal

Tags: python, linux, unix, terminal

I am using Windows and want to run a python script that connects to a remote linux terminal and sends some commands, then returns the result of those commands. What is the best way to do this in python?

Comment: Probably to write code that connects then prints the result.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was looking for a library that was appropriate for the task. I should have worded the question to make that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to ssh to the *nix host.  I use the paramiko python library to do this.  See the documentation in the link below.

http://www.paramiko.org/

Like this:

```
import paramiko

host='hostname'

# Make the connection
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host)

# Somehting like this to run the command:
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("command --arg 1 --arg 2")

# Close connection
ssh.close()
```

See docs on security in the paramiko site.   You may need to change how the authentication is handled depending on if you are using keys, or a password, etc.